# Python - automaticly zip specific folders/files

Tags: python, zip

I have been getting into Python lately and have come across a problem wich i think i could solve using it.
I have a USB stick with a lot of folders in there, the folders each contain the following:

```
/HTML5/
/Images/
foldername.html
foldername.ofp
preview.html
profile.xml
```

Now, i have to create a zip file of each folder, but only containing the Images folder and the profile.xml file. There is 40ish folders in there and there will be more in the future.

Here is the final code:

```
# Script to zip Foldername/Images/ and Foldername/profile.xml to Foldername.zip

import os
import zipfile

dirname = "D:\\testdir"

for schoen in os.listdir(dirname):
    print schoen
    myZipFile = zipfile.ZipFile(schoen+".zip", "w" )
    for f in os.listdir(os.path.join(dirname, schoen)):
        print f
        if f == "Profile.xml":
            print "Found profile.xml"
            myZipFile.write(schoen + "\\" + f, f)
        elif f == "Images":
            print "Found Images"
            myZipFile.write(schoen + "\\" + f, f)
    myZipFile.close()
```

Many thanks, 
Grootie

Comment: If you searched harder you should be able to find tutorials that will help you work with files and directories.  Searching for "python tutorial listing files" got this [helpful guide](http://www.diveintopython.net/file_handling/os_module.html) that should start you onto the right path for dealing with files and directories.

Comment: When editing your question, don't leave the existing question untouched and tack on an "Edit:" at the end. Edit the main body of the question to be as useful as possible to anyone who wants to help you, or anyone with a similar problem (just so long as you don't change it into a completely different question that makes the comments and answers no longer relevant). The history of your question is not important (and if anyone cares, SO tracks edit history); the information that people coming from the front page or google see is what matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of finding random code and trying to guess what it might mean and what you should change, why not look it up in the documentation?

The parameters to [`ZipFile.write`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.write) are:

```
ZipFile.write(filename, arcname=None, compress_type=None)
```

So your code copies the file named `profile.xml` into the archive under the name `images\\test.py`. Is that really what you want? I doubt it. But I'm not sure what you *do* want. You need to figure that out, in terms you could explain to an idiot (because computers are idiots). Then the docs—or SO, if you get confused by the docs—can help you translate that explanation into the appropriate code.

Comment: Ah, i think i understand it a bit better now, I updated the OP, am I going in the right direction?

Comment: No. Where did that `$folder.zip` come from? Do you really want a `$` in the filename? Do you really want to use the name of the zipfile as the name of all of the files inside the archive?

Comment: Yea, I was not clear, i wrote some code again and i think im closing in on the solution. Updated the OP again.